# How to measure and set the width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to make sub-navigation to measure its parents width and then set its own width accordingly. At the moment every sub-navigation (.primary-navigation ul ul) gets an individual class (customWidth-0 + i). Then using this class I measure its parent's width and set the width minus the padding. It's all working nice and fine, but I'm learning and I'd like to shorten the script. I was trying to loop this, use "this", but seem to get stuck at every point. It would be nice to learn to do this in a proper, robust way. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( ) {
    jQuery(".primary-navigation ul ul").each(function(i) {

        i = i+1;

        jQuery(this).addClass("customWidth-0" + i);
    });

    a = jQuery(".customWidth-01").prev().parent().width();
    b = jQuery(".customWidth-02").prev().parent().width();
    c = jQuery(".customWidth-03").prev().parent().width();
    d = jQuery(".customWidth-04").prev().parent().width();

    jQuery(".customWidth-01").css("width", a-31);
    jQuery(".customWidth-02").css("width", b-31);
    jQuery(".customWidth-03").css("width", c-31);
    jQuery(".customWidth-04").css("width", d-31);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your look and added my code after commenting your sections out and got the same thing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( ) {
        jQuery(".primary-navigation ul ul").each(function(i) {

            i = i+1;
            var _this = jQuery(this), w = _this.parents('ul').width();
            _this.css("width", (w-31)+"px");
            //jQuery(this).addClass("customWidth-0" + i);
            console.log(i);
        });
     /* 
        a = jQuery(".customWidth-01").prev().parent().width();
        b = jQuery(".customWidth-02").prev().parent().width();
        c = jQuery(".customWidth-03").prev().parent().width();
        d = jQuery(".customWidth-04").prev().parent().width();

        jQuery(".customWidth-01").css("width", a-31);
        jQuery(".customWidth-02").css("width", b-31);
        jQuery(".customWidth-03").css("width", c-31);
        jQuery(".customWidth-04").css("width", d-31);
     */
    });
</script>
```

It will find the div above given ul and take its width take off 31px and then apply it to given elements below. The LI elements inside of the UL will already have a 100% width and conform to that standard. If you wanted to you could just apply a `position: relative;` on the LIs of the .primary-navigation and then `position: absolute; left: 0; top: ~20px;` (top is a little skewed according to your em size.. This will do the same thing except it won't wrap your children and make it look weird.

If you gave me an exact image of what you wanted your menu to look like (not using javascript or anything maybe a designed version??) I could probably do a better job as this is still kinda hard to answer. Hopefully the code I provided helps you if not leave another comment and let me know if you have questions.

Below line is old answer.

---

Set a variable

```
var _this = jQuery(this), w = _this.parent().parent().width();
_this.css("width", (w-31)+"px");// just to be safe added px use w/e or leave blank it assumes it
```

This should work for you the same as you have it in the foreach.

you could also use `.parents('ul')`

```
w = _this.parents('ul').width();
```

Comment: I tried using your code, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. To put it simply, main navigation has children that have sub navigation. That sub navigation is visible on hover. I'd like that sub navigation be exactly the same width as its parent. For example, when you open a particular page the link text becomes bold, therefore it takes up more space in the navigation. So the width of the sub navigation has to be longer. Not sure whether this illustrates my point well, but here is a rough example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarkevicius/b2ymryp0/

Comment: Thanks Cayce. I tried using your suggested code, but for some reason it measures the wrong element and therefore sets the width wrong. This is the image of the layout: http://i60.tinypic.com/23p37s.png

Comment: OK that should help a lot more. I was kinda guessing on some stuff. Let me take a look a little later as I can't right this minute, but if you resolve it before hand that is fine. I will let you know asap. Hopefully someone else can resolve it before me so you don't have to wait too long.

Comment: going to try to throw something together real fast. Are your list items ALWAYS going to be (two letters and a number) "LL 1" ???

Comment: List items will depend on the page title, so lengths will vary. At the moment, it's just sample content in there. Thanks Cayce.

Comment: Not yet I"m sorry I've been very swamped with my life ... Can you add your html of the exact way you have it laid out. (in your post.. I am a little limited at this point.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function() {
        $('.primary-navigation').children('li').each(
    function(index) {
        var parentWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).children('ul').width(parentWidth/2);
        }
    );
```

Is this what you are looking for? now all the sub menu is 1/2 of parent.  you need to fix it to your specific need.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/La07pvf2/

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do the trick. Width = parentwidth-31pixels. To put it simply, main navigation has children that have sub navigation. That sub navigation is visible on hover. I'd like that sub navigation be exactly the same width as its parent. For example, when you open a particular page the link text becomes bold, therefore it takes up more space in the navigation. So the width of the sub navigation has to be longer. Not sure whether this illustrates my point well, but here is a rough example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarkevicius/b2ymryp0/